# Query Rule not Firing on Site

Tags: search, search-results, query-rule

I have created a query rule to sort my search results with those created latest appearing first.

[image: Building the Query]

The test results show this is running and ordering as expected.

[image: Query Test Results]

The problem is that when I do the same search on the site it does not give me the expected results.

The Query Rule has been created from Site Settings > Query Rules.

Why is the rule not firing on the site but is on the query test?